# Drive issue with python NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to use nltk in python, but am receiving a pop up error (windows) describing that I am missing a drive at the moment I call `import nltk`

Does anyone know why or how to fix this?

The error is below:

`"There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \Device\Harddisk4\DR4."`

Comment: How did you install `nltk`? Which OS are you using?

Comment: through anaconda, on windows.

Comment: run `cmd.exe`, run `python`, type `import nltk` in the python interpreter, then post what happens.

Answer (score 4):

NLTK searches for `nltk_data` directory until it finds one.

On Windows, these locations are scanned: `%userprofile%\nltk_data`, `C:\nltk_data`, `D:\nltk_data`, and so on.

Installing NLTK data or creating an empty directory solves the error.

http://www.nltk.org/data.html

My installation is Win 10, Python 3.5.2 64-bit, nltk 3.2.1 (Christoph Gohlke's binary).

Answer (score 1):

While i am not sure exactly where the problem arises, I had this same error happen to me (it started 'overnight' - the code had been working, i hand not re-installed nltk, so i have no idea what caused it to start happening). I still had the problem after upgrading to the latest version of nltk (3.2.1), and re-downloading the nltk data.

`shiratori`'s answer helped me solve my problem, although at least for me it was slightly more complicated. Specifically, my nltk data was stored in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data` (i think this is a default location). This is where it had always been stored, and always had worked fine, however suddenly nltk did not seem to be recognizing this location, and hence looked in the next drive. To solve it, I copied and pasted all the data in that folder to `C:\nltk_data` and now it is running fine again.

Anyway, not sure if this is Windows induced problem, or what exactly changed to cause code that was working to stop working, but this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Win 7, Python 3.6.5, nltk 3.3).

A simpler solution is to just define the Windows environment variable `NLTK_DATA`. In my case (like @kyrenia), the data is in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\nltk_data`.

This solution is described in the nltk 3.3 documentation: http://www.nltk.org/data.html

> If you did not install the data to one of the above central locations, you will need to set the NLTK_DATA environment variable to specify the location of the data. (On a Windows machine, right click on “My Computer” then select Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables > User Variables > New...)